# Book with Animal on Earth being invaded by humans (Humans Are The Monsters Trope)

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic, alien-invasion

The book is set up like your average "invasion" trope, where the pov is watching its home getting invaded, we're lead to believe that we're reading from a human POV (Or, it's not suggested otherwise)

The twist at the end, is however, that humans are actually the enemy! They're the invading species, and the POV we're been reading from is actually a Sloth.

It was probably a really obscure book, published around the 60's/70's.

Comment: Is this a book or a short story? It doesn't sound complex enough to be a full length novel.

Comment: There's a 1948 short story "No Connection" by Asimov where bears have their land invaded by "Eekahs" who turn out to be apes (humans having destroyed themselves in a nuclear war).

Comment: The Randall Garrett short story "Despoilers of the Golden Empire" reads like a sci fi story, but is actually historical. I don't remember it being from the POV of sloths, but of the historical protagonist. It is set in South America so sloths may be involved!